# How to click on button on html page load using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Below are script that I found on other stackoverflow questions, however it doesn't work.

I want the script to click on play button and then load a video modal.

URL : https://www.scalperstrategy.com/

```
    <body>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".mbr-media.show-modal.align-center.py-2").trigger("click");
   });``
</script>
```

Thanks all!

Comment: It doesn't work probably because you didn't add jQuery to your page.

Comment: you've not added `jquery` on your page. add a jQuery `cdn` link or from your local server and this should work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use .click() function to achieve the same

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSave").click(
            function () {
                AlertSave();
            }            
        );

        $("#btnSave").click();
    });

function AlertSave() {
   alert("Alert Message OnClick");
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yo7pku0m/)

However, if all you are trying to achieve is to call an event that you bind on click, you can just call this event instead.

Comment: is this correct ?

   <script>
$(window).load(function(){

  $(document).ready(function () {

        $("span#click").click(
            function () {
                AlertSave();
            }            
        );
        
        $("span#click").click();
    });

function AlertSave() {
   alert("Watch Xscalper in ACTION!");
}


});

</script>

Comment: I'd like to know if my answer is incorrect as it was downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

after adding jquery and below script it finally work

```
<script type="text/javascript">


   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(".mbr-media.show-modal.align-center.py-2").trigger("click");
   });
</script>
```